# Browserify bundle js, but require("jquery-datetimepicker") does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I use gulp + browserify to bundle my javascript file.
I `npm install select2 --save`

```
require("select2");

module.exports = {
    init: function() {
        $('#datetime-start').datetimepicker({
            dayOfWeekStart : 1,
            lang:'en',
            disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
            startDate:  '1986/01/05'
        });
    }
}
```

this block of code works well, but then I `npm install jquery-datetimepicker --save`.
then I write some code again:

```
require("jquery-datetimepicker");

module.exports = {
    init: function() {
        $('#datetime-start').datetimepicker({})
    }
}
```

browserify bundle is successfull, but when I open the browser, there is an error:

> $(...).datetimepicker is not a function.

May be I miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jquery-datetimepicker` exports its factory function which receives jquery as parameter to populate it (see [here](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/ec0865991d9d15e895e516cfbfdeee63f7e998b6/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js#L589)), but seems it overrides by [`jquery-mousewheel` exports object](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/ec0865991d9d15e895e516cfbfdeee63f7e998b6/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js#L2986). Definitely its an issue and discussed in issues [#412](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/412) and [#496](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/496). Although workaround exist to get it working:

First:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install jquery-datetimepicker --save
npm install jquery-mousewheel --save
npm install https://github.com/kartik-v/php-date-formatter.git#closure --save
```

**Note:** `php-date-formatter` installed from `#closure` branch as master branch does not support umd pattern.

then:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
DateFormatter = require('php-date-formatter')($);
require('jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js')($);
require('jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js')($);

module.exports = {
    init: function() {
        $('#datetime-start').datetimepicker({})
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry， it still does not work.  do you think should I add some more config to package.json's browserify-shim

Comment: I think require("jquery-datetimepicker")($) still not attach datetimepicker to window.$, just $ variable.

Comment: It seems `jquery-datetimepicker` overrides its `exports` object with the `exports` object of `jquery-mousewheel`. of course this is an issue and discussed in issues [#412](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/412) and [#496](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/496). and most promising solution is proposed by @wankdanker. answer updated.

Comment: another problem: bundle is ok, but when brower open page, throw an error Uncaught TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Comment: I still not understand, why just require('jquery-datetimepicker')($) not working, I saw the jquery.datetimepicker.js source code, just $.datetimepicker = {}.

Comment: When you `require('jquery-datetimepicker')`, this loads `jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js` and in this file after exporting datetime factory there also another export which exports `jquery-mousewheel` factory. and this one overrides the previous export. so you should require them one by one to prevent this collision.

Comment: `require()` is not a function means you does not browserify your module. note that you should rebundle after every change you made in modules.

Comment: I npm install php-date-formatter directly, and bundle is ok, but when open page with browser, throw the error: require is not one function

Comment: As i noted php-date-formatter does not support CommonJS you should install it from the `#closure` branch: `npm install https://github.com/kartik-v/php-date-formatter.git#closure --save`